# Viewing a Compiler error output

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-construction

I am new to Netbeans and I am given a simple exercise by my professor to find the compiler errors in a given program. This is a simple hello world program but all I get is

```
Compiling 1 source file to D:\UCC\CS6312-Mobile Devices and Systems\Lab\MyFirstMIDlet\build\compiled
D:\UCC\CS6312-Mobile Devices and Systems\Lab\MyFirstMIDlet\src\myfirstmidlet\MyFirstMIDlet.java:12: error: ';' expected
    form.addCommand(exit)
1 error
D:\UCC\CS6312-Mobile Devices and Systems\Lab\MyFirstMIDlet\nbproject\build-impl.xml:359: Compile failed; **see the compiler error output for details.**
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

So I want to know where I can find the details of the compiler errors as I have to include those in my assignment. Thank you

Comment: Ummm, it is **`D:\UCC\CS6312-Mobile Devices and Systems\Lab\MyFirstMIDlet\src\myfirstmidlet\MyFirstMIDlet.java:12: error: ';' expected
    form.addCommand(exit)`** The trick is, that the compiler does **not** display all the errors in one go... You have to **fix each error** to get to the next one... This assignment is not that easy as it seemed!

Comment: Thanks. But the systems in my lab display all the compiler errors in one log but my machine is not showing. Is there any way to display the compiler errors like the output log?

Answer (score 0):

The compile error is the first bit of the error message:

> D:\UCC\CS6312-Mobile Devices and Systems\Lab\MyFirstMIDlet\src\myfirstmidlet\MyFirstMIDlet.java:12: error: ';' expected
>       form.addCommand(exit)

This could mean exactly what it says, and that you're missing a semicolon on this line, but doesn't necessarily - it might be something else that's wrong that's causing the compiler to produce that error. You may also run into the case where you fix that error then have to fix some others that come up afterwards - such is the nature of compilers!